# Qui s'enfuit, déjà, dans la chanson de Jacques Brel ?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

La chanson *Ne me quitte pas* de Jacques Brel commence ainsi :

> Ne me quitte pas
>   Il faut oublier
>   Tout peut s'oublier
>   **Qui s'enfuit déjà**
>   Oublier le temps
>   Des malentendus
>   Et le temps perdu
>   (…)

Ma théorie est qu'il y a ici une inversion et que la phrase est en fait *« Oublier le temps des malentendus qui s'enfuit déjà »*. Pouvez-vous confirmer ou infirmer (et corriger) ma théorie ?

Comment: C’est comme ça que je le lis souvent, mais cela pourrait très bien être le « tout ». « Tout ce qui s’enfuit déjà peut s’oublier ».

Comment: Sympathique commentaire, mais pourquoi ne pas en faire une réponse ?

Comment: Parce que ce n’est guère argumenté. Si d’aventure j’en ai le temps…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[D'abord connaître la source](http://fra.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200800612).*

Il ne s'agit pas d'un français d'académie, mais l'expression poétique de la tragédie de l'amour non partagé, et de la faiblesse humaine.

Alors la licence poétique permet de traduire l'affolement du cœur en une suite discontinue de jaillissements de la pensée qui bien que contigus ne sont pas exactement liés.

Relire le paragraphe, écouter Brel, chanter ce passage en boucle, sans l'analyser mais en essayant de percevoir quelles sont les émotions qui surgissent ... jusqu'à ce que cela semble évident peut être un exercice de compréhension puissant.

Le lien d'*@air-dex* montre Muriel Robin en bataille avec la sémantique, son ego et ses manies de décortiquer la lettre en oubliant l'esprit.

Comme *@Un francophone* le lit, on peut rattacher la ligne à *tout*, mais on peut aussi constater ce *qui* qui s'enfuit déjà, *qui* pouvant être la cause de la rupture amoureuse, ou la douleur de la séparation qui s'estompe, l'amour qui s'éloigne *déjà* augmentant le désespoir d'une reconquête impossible ... chacun peut s'y projeter ou s'y retirer dans un vide vibrant de souvenirs.

Le *qui* représentant en lui-même un *tout* lié aux souvenirs d'une passion passée.

Comment: Plussoyé. Dans votre réponse, pourriez-vous expliciter l'acception d'`un vide vibrant`? Un vide, comment peut-il s'avérer vibrant ?

Comment: @LePressentiment Le vide renvoie ici au Vide extrême oriental, où le vide est énergie (soit vibrante, soit fluctuante) qui alimente la Conscience universelle, conscience qui est partagée par tous, mais dont peu en ont une perception dénuée de toute illusion, de tout voile.

Comment: À votre bon cœur !

Answer (score 6):

Pour moi, c'est le *tout* qui non seulement peut être oublié mais s'enfuit déjà (c'est-à-dire est déjà en train d’être oublié).

Answer (score 3):

Ce peut être aussi une manière de dire :

Tout ce qui s'enfuit déjà peut être oublié.

Answer (score 2):

Le mieux placé pour répondre serait Jacques Brel mais ce n'est pas possible. :-)

Le problème de cette phrase est le "*qui*". Que désigne-t-il ? Les deux temps (celui des malentendus et le temps perdu) ? L'un des deux temps ? "*Tout*" (dont les deux temps par définition du mot) ?

Personnellement je pencherais plutôt pour une inversion :

> Tout peut s'oublier [dont] le temps des malentendus et le temps perdu, qui s'enfuient déjà.

À noter que Muriel Robin a déjà tenté de répondre à cette question par le passé : http://youtu.be/GBmycYD_24M